# Jenkins JaCoCo Plugin: jacoco/classes does not exist

Tags: android, jenkins, jacoco

I am able to get the coveage file but from Jenkins I always get an error, On Ubuntu 14.04, get Code Coverage in **/coverage.ec but Jenkins gives me an ERROR

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: basedir /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android_Build_TestCC/builds/22/jacoco/classes does not exist
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner.scan(DirectoryScanner.java:550)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFileAndDirectoryNames(FileUtils.java:1717)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFileNames(FileUtils.java:1645)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFileNames(FileUtils.java:1627)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFiles(FileUtils.java:1601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFiles(FileUtils.java:1584)
at hudson.plugins.jacoco.ExecutionFileLoader.analyzeStructure(ExecutionFileLoader.java:124)
at hudson.plugins.jacoco.ExecutionFileLoader.loadBundleCoverage(ExecutionFileLoader.java:133)
at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportDir.parse(JacocoReportDir.java:102)
at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoBuildAction.loadRatios(JacocoBuildAction.java:291)
at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoBuildAction.load(JacocoBuildAction.java:273)
at hudson.plugins.jacoco.JacocoPublisher.perform(JacocoPublisher.java:371)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
at  hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Build step 'Record JaCoCo coverage report' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: screenshot of the configuration?

Comment: Configuration of Jenkins Config ?

Comment: This error usually comes if you have a post action plugin for publishing Jacoco code coverage results (using .exec file(s), build/classes/main or target/classes/main and your main source code (src/main/java or src/java etc instead of test source code folders) if the build fails before it generates the class files (i.e. if checkout failed, or it failed in compliation and ended up going to post action where it'll says i can't find my class files). I assume you are giving **/**.exec (not ec files), <pathto>/classes/main and src/main/java or src/java in the Jacoco post publish field boxes, right?

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused if you have spaces in the following fields of the Jenkins Jacoco plugin: Path to exec files, Inclusions, Path to class directories, Exclusions

See the following Jenkins' bug:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22776

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12673631)

Comment: The link says that this problem could be caused by spaces in the fields which is what I said before I included the link.  The answer would stand on it's own without the link